# Car will not start unless AC is turned on

Tags: battery, toyota, starting, ac, corolla

My car Toyota Corolla will not turn on unless my AC is in the on position why is that? If I get a jump the car will turn on but die immediately unless the air conditioner is in the **on position**

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Toyota? It sounds like the engine/electronics is grounding through the AC or something like that. Very strange.

Comment: Was there an attempt at idle speed adjustment? Was the throttle body ever cleaned? Any modifications to engine? Most engines kick idle rpm up when ac is turned on because of the load compressors create on small engines. This may explain how the engine runs with ac turned on but won't with ac off. What maintenance, if any, were performed?